# What tools or libraries used in your company to speed up the development and ensure the quality?

Tags: visual-studio

As far as I know some company will use Devexpress to speed up the UI design
some company might use the AssistX .

another question:
is there any plugin which can help to keep a eye on our company 's code convention? If someone don't follow the convention, visual studio will warn him ?

Comment: Have you looked at FxCop (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28VS.80%29.aspx) and StyleCop (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Agent Smith](http://www.agentsmithplugin.com/) for [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is what we use where I work that seems pretty good about some conventions.